# Filtrar descarga de archivos desde gitlab

Tags: gitlab, jenkins

Hola a todas y todos :

Con Jenkins, pretendo automatizar las transferencias de archivos desde distintos ambientes de desarrollo en nuestra unidad. Para ello, la idea es que descargue los archivos desde la rama "producción". Sin embargo necesito poder filtrar, para que no descargue todos los archivos sino los necesarios.

Entiendo que con .gitignore se puede filtrar lo que se sube al repositorio de gitlab. ¿Puedo también indicarle qué archivos debe descargar (Y cuales no)?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. El archivo `.gitignore` mantiene su uso sólo para controlar lo que puede añadirse al repositorio Git (al local y por ende, al remoto).

Para lo que buscas existe `git clone --filter` y `git sparse-checkout` que, juntos, descargan sólo los archivos deseados.

Por ejemplo, para clonar sólo los archivos del subdirectorio `/small` en el repositorio de prueba `https://github.com/cirosantilli/test-git-partial-clone-big-small-no-bigtree`, se haría algo así:

```
git clone -n --depth=1 --filter=tree:0 \
  https://github.com/cirosantilli/test-git-partial-clone-big-small-no-bigtree
cd test-git-partial-clone-big-small-no-bigtree
git sparse-checkout set --no-cone small
git checkout
```

- Clonas el repo indicando profundidad 1 y filtrando para no descargar nada aún más allá de la metadata y las carpetas de primer nivel.
- Entras a la carpeta del repo recién clonado
- Usas la opción sparse-checkout de git para que quede configurado que descargue sólo el subdirectorio `/small`. Aquí aún no has copiado nada; sólo se ha editado un archivo `sparsecheckout`.
- Haces git checkout común y corriente para que jale los archivos indicados.

Fuente: [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52269934/236345)